# How do I fix this annoying warning to use an alternative JSON library

Tags: heroku

how do I get rid of this annoying warning whenever I run the heroku-toolbelt.

```
God@Heaven$heroku list
/usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/stack.rb:64: warning: already initialized constant IN
/usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/stack.rb:68: warning: already initialized constant OUT
[WARNING] MultiJson is using the default adapter (ok_json).We recommend loading a different JSON library to improve performance.
=== My Apps
...
```

Comment: @Vova Unfortunately no, but I did an OS wipe as part of spring cleaning, and it stopped giving it to me on Ubuntu 14.04.